# remove index.php from URL htaccess in OHS

Tags: php, oracle, apache, .htaccess

I currently have something(done with Codeigniter) running on OHS-Oracle HTTP server.
Before moving to OHS, I use Apache and i have following .htaccess file works perfectly.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /pssecforms/
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But now it's not working on OHS.  What should I do to make this works?

Comment: Given that the OHS Oracle HTTP server is just a proprietary implementation of open source Apache, all of the above should work just fine. My thoughts are that `mod_rewrite` is not currently enabled.

Comment: I checked phpinfo and it seems like mod_rewrite was enabled.          Apache Version  Apache/2.2.3 (Oracle)
Server Administrator  root@localhost
Loaded Modules (....) mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias mod_rewrite (....)